# jquery img src replace doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, string, dom-manipulation

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to get image src and replace the src. I can get the image using the function mentioned below but i cannot get the src.

```
<div class="class1">

<a href="Link1"><img src="//abc.com/1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="Link2"><img src="//abc.com/2.jpg"/></a>
<a href="Link3"><img src="//abc.com/3.jpg"/></a>
<a href="Link4"><img src="//abc.com/4.jpg"/></a>
.
.
.
<a href="Linkn"><img src="//abc.com/n.jpg"/></a>

</div>
```

This function doesn't work but this is what i need to do. I would like to get the src and replace the .jpg at the end with -xyz.jpg for all the images.

'galleryImg': $(this).children('img') return the image but when i add .attr('src'), it stops working

```
function () {
var $gallery = $('.class1 a');
return $gallery.map(function () {
    return {
        'galleryLink': $(this).attr('href'),
        'galleryImg': $(this).children('img').attr('src').replace('.jpg','-xyz.jpg')
    };
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) in a wrong way.

First, `attr('src')` will only retrieve the current value, after changing it, you have to use `attr('src', newvalue)` to set it.

Second, `attr()` will only work on the first element of the collection. If you have more than one elements, you can use an [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loop on them, or [call `attr()` with a function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#computed-attr-values) that will run for every attribute value, and the returned value will be set as the attribute's new value.

Here is an example for the latter ([and a little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xRuu9/)):

```
$('.class1').find('img').attr('src', function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/\.jpg$/,'-xyz.jpg');
});
```

This is all explained in detail in the documentation, which I recommend you read.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.